# Having issue when plotting an equation with scattering points

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I plot an equation with a given intercept and slope together with scattering some random points, the equation line is shown in half (please refer the image that I shared below). I could not find how to properly search this problem. That's why if this is asked before, I'd appreciate, if someone can share the link with me. Otherwise, here is my issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#intercept = Slope(w) 
#slope = Intercept(w)

intercept = 0.6 # For simplicity, let's assign fixed numbers
slope = 0.75

axes = plt.gca()
x_vals = np.array(axes.get_xlim())
y_vals = intercept + slope * x_vals
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
plt.scatter(0, 0.5, color="blue")
plt.scatter(-1, -1, color="red")
plt.show()
```

Here how my image looks when I plot it; https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXKy7.jpg.

My question, how do I obtain a proper line while still plotting the points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are getting the `x_vals` you used `axes.get_xlim())` which gets the minimum and maximum `x` values. When you plotted the scatter points, the size of the plot increased.

Change the order of your code:

```
axes = plt.gca()

plt.scatter(0, 0.5, color="blue")
plt.scatter(-1, -1, color="red")
x_vals = np.array(axes.get_xlim())
y_vals = intercept + slope * x_vals
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals)
plt.show()
```